# Why does reverse this function not work

Tags: c++, cuda

In the constructor I fill the array on the device side.

but now I want to execute reverse function on the array.

```
 using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>


__global__ void generateVector(int *data,int count){
    int tid = blockIdx.x;
    data[tid] = -tid;
}

__global__ void reverseArray(int *data,int count){
    int tid = blockIdx.x;
    data[tid] = tid;
}

class FData{
private:
    int *data;
    int size;
public:
    FData(int sizeP){
        size = sizeP;
        data = new int[size];
        int *devA;

        cudaMalloc((void**) &devA, size * sizeof(int));
        generateVector<<<size,1>>>(devA,size);
        cudaMemcpy(data,devA, size * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        cudaFree(devA);
    }

    ~FData(){
        delete [] data;
    }

    int getSize(){
        return size;
    }



    int elementAt(int i){
        return data[i];
    }

    void reverse(){
        int *devA;
        cudaMalloc((void**) &devA, sizeof(int));
        reverseArray<<<size,1>>>(devA,size);
        cudaMemcpy(data,devA,size * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaFree(devA);

    }


};


int main(void) {

    FData arr(30);

    cout << arr.elementAt(1);


    arr.reverse();
    cout << arr.elementAt(1);


    return 0;

}
```

It still prints the values which I filled in the constructor. What is the problem here? How can i solve it? What is going wrong?

Comment: maybe it works fine, what are the elements before and after

Comment: it's unrelated, but you have a memory leak (you need to call `delete []` on your `data` member variable in a destructor). Also you need to free all of your CUDA memory, which you're not doing

Comment: Try some cuda error checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kernels aren't reversing anything. They're just negating the values, so if anything I would be quite surprised if you saw anything get reversed. With that said, if you add error checking to your code (see [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on how best to do the error checking) then you'll see that your code will fail on the call to `cudaMalloc` in your `reverse` function. You can fix this by changing `devA` to be a plain pointer (it doesn't really make sense for you to be allocating it as a host-array anyways, as you're not using it on the host to begin with).

```
void reverse(){
    int *devA;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &devA, size * sizeof(int));       
    reverseArray<<<size,1>>>(devA,size);
    cudaMemcpy(data,devA,size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(devA);
}
```

Also, you should free your memory too, you have both host-side and device-side memory leaks. Whenever you have a `cudaMalloc` call, you should havea  corresponding `cudaFree`. Also, consider adding a destructor to free your host-side `data` member, as you have a memory leak there too.

```
~FData()
{
    delete [] data;
}
```

Comment: It works for me, maybe try posting your updated code and I can take a look

Comment: @asdasd look at your call to cudaMalloc in your reverse function. You're allocating 1 int on the device. You need to allocate `size` number of ints.

Comment: Also I should point out that if you had error checking in your code then you would have likely caught it earlier, as you'll be doing 29 out-of-bounds memory accesses in your kernel